# Function to create cluster based on two unique column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to create a "cluster index" based on combinations of pairs from two columns. If there are two combinations of numbers it should get its own cluster id in a new, third column.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am sure there is a way to do this in pandas, just haven't figured it out yet.

```
#input dataframe
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,8,8], 'col2': [3,4,7,13,13,2,2,2,7,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I am looking for some sort of function that creates the output like this:

```
#expected output dataframe
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,8,8], 'col2': [3,4,7,13,13,2,2,2,7,7],'cluster':[0,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]}
df_cluster = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_cluster
```

Comment: `col1` and `col2` also has changed in df_cluster. is that expected?

Comment: @ggaurav thank you for pointing that out.  I fixed it.  No, col1 and col2 should be the same and the only thing that should happen is column three created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_info` of `grouper` object

```
df['cluster'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).grouper.group_info[0]
df
```

[image]

Comment: perfect.  Interesting, haven't used those methods before.  Why group_info[0]?

Comment: `group_info` is a tuple and have other details like no of groups. `group_info[0]` is the group numbers